# How to use keep-alive in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

Basically, I want to keep alive 2 components in `router-view` and it works, however, I don't know if I am doing it correctly.

```
 <keep-alive include="users, data">
    <router-view></router-view>
 </keep-alive>
```

users and data are route names. Is this correct way to do it. Are there any disadvantages of `keep-alive`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The only disadvantage is that these components are kept in memory and therefore their state is saved and not reset.

You also lose lifecycle hooks like created, mounted, etc. since the component is not being rebuilt from scratch anymore. You can replace those lifecycle hooks with hooks that are specific to `keep-alive` components. For example:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#activated

Whether `keep-alive` is a disadvantage or advantage is entirely up to your scenario. If you want to keep the state because you want to switch fast and often between the `keep-alive` components, it could be an advantage. If you really rely on a clean state through components being built and destroyed, it could be a disadvantage.

Answer (score 6):

**1. We can achieve it by using**

```
<keep-alive>
// Render component inside
</keep-alive>
```

special tag which has provided by vueJs.

**2. use life cycle hooks:**

a. activated()

b. deactivated()