# I'm losing content of the elements when I'm navigating by Vue Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, reload, vue-router

I'm trying to create a simple SPA using Vue Router and the Vuetify framework. I have several components connected to my router. When I first reload a view, everything works fine, but when I move from that view and come back, I completely lose the contents of it.

Here is HTML code:

```
<template>
  <v-layout fill-height id="map" class="cadetblue" style="width: 100%">
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="500">
      <v-card>
        <v-img src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/sunshine.jpg" height="200px"></v-img>

        <v-card-title primary-title>
          <div>
            <div class="headline">Select layers</div>
            <span class="grey--text">Some layers are avaliable</span>
          </div>
        </v-card-title>

        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn icon @click="layers = !layers">
            <v-icon>{{ layers ? 'keyboard_arrow_down' : 'keyboard_arrow_up' }}</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>

        <v-slide-y-transition>
          <v-card-text v-show="true">
            <v-checkbox @change="clickMew()" id="dofLayer" label="DOF"></v-checkbox>
            <v-checkbox name="tkLayer" id="tkLayer" label="TK25"></v-checkbox>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-slide-y-transition>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
    <v-flex>
      <v-btn
        absolute
        id="zoomIn"
        @click="zoomIn()"
        dark
        fab
        top
        left
        small
        color="pink"
        class="mt-5"
      >
        <v-icon>add</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn
        absolute
        id="zoomOut"
        @click="zoomOut()"
        dark
        fab
        top
        left
        small
        color="pink"
        class="mt-6"
      >
        <v-icon>remove</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn absolute id="home" @click="home()" dark fab top left small color="green" class="mt-7">
        <v-icon>home</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-speed-dial
        class="mb-5"
        fixed
        bottom
        right
        direction="top"
        transition="slide-y-reverse-transition"
      >
        <v-btn slot="activator" id="test" color="blue darken-2" dark fab>
          <v-icon>account_circle</v-icon>
        </v-btn>

        <v-btn fab id="addLayer" dark small color="green">
          <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
        </v-btn>

        <v-btn fab @click="dialog = true" dark small color="green">
          <v-icon>layers</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-speed-dial>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>
```

And here are script part:

```
import {
  map,
  initMap,
  interactivity,
  zoomIn,
  zoomOut,
  home,
  addHok,
  consoleMsg
} from "../../scripts/cro";

export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
      links: [
        { icon: "account_circle", color: "blue darken-2" },
        { icon: "edit", color: "green" },
        { icon: "add", color: "indigo" }
      ],
      neven: "TEsting Neven",
      dialog: false,
      layers: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    zoomIn() {
      zoomIn();
    },
    zoomOut() {
      zoomOut();
    },
    home() {
      home();
    },
    clickMew() {
      addHok();
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      initMap();
    });
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      initMap();
      consoleMsg();
      // interactivity();
    });
  }
};
```

Here is the router page (router.js):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Dashboard from './views/Dashboard.vue'
import Projects from './views/Projects.vue'
import Team from './views/Team.vue'

    Vue.use(Router)

    export default new Router({
      mode: 'history',
      base: process.env.BASE_URL,
      routes: [
        {
          path: '/',
          name: 'dashboard',
          component: Dashboard
        },
        {
          path: '/projects',
          name: 'projects',
          component: Projects
        },
        {
          path: '/team',
          name: 'team',
          component: Team
        }
      ]
    })
```

**UPDATE**

As ljubadr pointed out, there is some workaround with `keep-alive`. I tried wrapping `router-view` like this:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <Navbar></Navbar>
    <Modal></Modal>
    <v-content>
        <keep-alive include="projects">
        <router-view></router-view>
        </keep-alive>
    </v-content>
    <Footer></Footer>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Here is App.vue

It did not help :(

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <Navbar></Navbar>
    <Modal></Modal>
    <v-content>
      <keep-alive include="projects">
        <router-view></router-view>
      </keep-alive>
    </v-content>
    <Footer></Footer>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from "@/components/NavBar";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer";
import Modal from "@/components/Modal";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: { Navbar, Footer, Modal }
};
</script>
```

Comment: You can use `<keep-alive include="foo">`. You can add more components there by using `,`. Check [this jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/L613xva0/4/). There are some [disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48502416/3226121) to this approach

Comment: @ljubadr I'm feeling that I'm one step closer. I 've added `<keep-alive include="projects">` but without any success. Maybe there is a problem with lifecycle hooks?

Comment: I think you also need `name: 'projects',` in your component for `include` to work

Comment: I've added but without any success so far

Comment: I've created basic [codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xMbwbq?editors=1011), if you look at the console, you will see that `component1` `created()` method is fired only once when you navigate between components. Not sure why it's not working in your case...

Comment: You could also try [this approach](http://jsfiddle.net/ygjg5znx/), where you can specify `keepAlive` in your [Route Meta Fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html)

Comment: @ljubadr Yes, that was it. Please submit answer for the purpose of accepting it :)

Comment: I've created the answer and I posted both solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<keep-alive>`. Read more about it [here](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view)

There are [some disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48502416/3226121) to this approach:

> you lose lifecycle hooks like **created**, **mounted**, etc. since the
>   component is not being rebuilt from scratch anymore. You can replace
>   those lifecycle hooks with hooks that are specific to keep-alive
>   components

**First approach**

You can then specify which components to **keep alive**, by specifying

```
<keep-alive include="component1,component2">
  <router-view></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

where those components need to have the matching `name` property:

```
name: 'component1'
```

**Second approach**

We can also use `<keep-alive>` with [Route Meta Fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html), where we have more granular control in the router on which components to keep alive (I've used the code from [this codepen by Linusborg](https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/L613xva0/4/))

**Router**

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', 
      component: Home,
      meta: { keepAlive: false } 
    },
    { path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      meta: { keepAlive: true }
    }
  ]
})
```

**Template**

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <keep-alive v-if="$route.meta.keepAlive">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </keep-alive>

  <router-view v-else></router-view>
</transition>
```